# AWS IoT to to send once-off real-time command to device

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, aws-iot

I have a weather station which is publishing to AWS IoT.

It reports it's state as well as measurements of the environment by publishing to shadows service messages of the format:

```
{
 "state": {
   "reported": {
      "temperature" : 22,
      "humidity" : 70,
       ....
      "wind" : 234,
      "air" : 345
   }
 }
```

---

The station has some interactive properties like `_led1` and `_led2` which I can also report and update via Shadows service by setting "desired" state. To do that I can send to a device message like that:

```
{
 "state": {
   "desired": {
      "_led1" : "on",
      "_led2" : "off",
       ....
      "_lock99" : "open"
   }
 }
```

Thanks to shadow service *Whenever device gets online* it will receive synchronized state and will turn the leds and locks into desired position.

However, **sometimes I want to operate the device in real-time**: when troubleshooting a device - I want to send a real-time command to reboot it - and if device is live and receives the message I want to reboot it. If device was offline, then nothing happens (the reboot command never reaches the device).

So what would be the best way to control device in real-time?  Still try to play with the shadows service to achieve that? Or simply create a separate topic eg. `my-things/{thing_name}/real-time-commands` and force device to subscribe to it?

Comment: May be overkill: [LwM2M](https://github.com/eclipse/leshan) could be cleaner approach.

Comment: You could add logic to your device to ignore certain parts of the device shadow if they were send when the device was offline.

Comment: Did you come to a conclusion?